# GKE GPU Timesharing Driver Capabilities

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I'm running `nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-base-ubuntu20.04` on Google Kubernetes Engine using GPU Timesharing on T4 gpus

Checking the driver capabilities I get compute and utility. I was hoping to also get graphics and video. Is this a limitation of Timesharing on GKE?

Comment: Do you want to know the Limitations of graphics and video  or limitations of Timesharing on GKE?

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu, yes that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

It should let you use the resources for graphics and video, however time-sharing GPU are ideal for workloads that are not using a high amount of the resources all the time.

[Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/timesharing-gpus#limitations) for using Time-Sharing GPU's on GKE's

- GKE enforces memory (address space) isolation, performance isolation, and fault isolation between containers that share a physical GPU. However, memory limits aren't enforced on time-shared GPUs. To avoid running into out-of-memory (OOM) issues, set GPU memory limits in your applications. To avoid security issues, only deploy workloads that are in the same trust boundary to time-shared GPUs.
- GKE might reject certain time-shared GPU requests to prevent unexpected behavior during capacity allocation
- The maximum number of containers that can share a single physical GPU is 48. When planning your time-sharing configuration, consider the resource needs of your workloads and the capacity of the underlying physical GPUs to optimize your performance and responsiveness.